# calculation of block quantities in a matrix in R

Tags: r

I have a very general question on data manipulations in R, and I am seeking a convenient and fast way. Suppose I have a matrix of dimension (R)-by-(nxm), i.e. R rows and n times m columns.

```
set.seed(999)
n = 5; m = 10; R = 100
ncol = m*n
mat = matrix(rnorm(n*m*R), nrow=R, ncol=ncol)
```

Now I want to have a new matrix (call it `new.mat`) of dimension (R)-by-(m), i.e. given a certain row of `mat`, I want to calculate a number (say sum) for the first `n` elements, then a number for the next `n` elements, and so on. In this way, the first row of `mat` ends up with `m` numbers. The same thing is done for every other row of `mat`.

For the given example above, the 1st element of the 1st row of the new matrix `new.mat` should be `sum(mat[1,1:5])`, the 2nd element is `sum(mat[1,6:10])`, and the last element is `sum(mat[1,46:50])`. The 2nd row of `new.mat` is `(sum(mat[2,1:5]), sum(mat[2,6:10),...)`.

If possible, avoiding `for` loops is preferred. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rowsum` is a useful function here. You will have to do a bit of `t`ransposing to get what you want

You need to create a grouping vector that is something like `c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,....,10,10,10,10,10)`

```
grp <- rep(seq_len(ceiling(ncol(mat)/5)), each = 5, length.out = ncol(mat))
# this will also work, but may be less clear why.
# grp <- (seq_len(ncol(mat))-1) %/%5
```

`rowsum` computes column sums across rows of a numeric matrix-like object for each level of a grouping variable

You are looking for row sums across columns, so you will have to transpose your results (and your input)

```
 t(rowsum(t(mat),grp))
```